# How are .swc files converted in to .swf files when "compiling" a Flash Builder application?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, compilation, flash-builder

I have the unfortunate constraint that I have to put a Flex application on a server that will not allow `.` in its filenames.

The Flex libraries (`.swc`) are somehow turned into `.swf` files in the process of 'compiling' the Flex application and their filenames are changed into `<FRAMEWORKNAME>_###.##.#.##.swf` and what I need to do is get those `.swf` files without the `.` characters.

What I'm looking for is any leads whatsoever before diving deeply into Google

Edit: I do not think that the libs are local to my company. They are in the flex_bin folder and have names like Framework_###.#.##.#, spark_#.#.##.#., etc.

Comment: Are the libs local to your company? how are you compiling the libs? is it thru flashbuilder? if so, the builder does not convert to any name it likes, if you are using command line or ant to compile, then check your ant file for the name you set.

Comment: @Zeus question updated. I'll start looking at command line/ant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the libraries provided by the Adobe, you can set the compiler options to merge these into one big SWC [file](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/UsingFlashBuilder/WS6f97d7caa66ef6eb1e63e3d11b6c4d0d21-7fe6.html). Check the link for *'Merge the SWC file into the application SWF file when compiled'* step.